# HTML5 tags for a search result list

Tags: html, semantic-markup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Marking up a search result list with HTML5 semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255109/marking-up-a-search-result-list-with-html5-semantics)

i've a list of items from a query to database. Now i want to display them to user via HTML.

My initial way is like this:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    search element 1
  </li>
  ...
</ol>
```

I'm wondering if there is a better semantic way with HTML5 like:

```
<article>
  <section>
    search element 1
  </section>
  ...
</article
```

Does anyone have a better semantic way?

Comment: user509375 You can refer to solution suggest in another discussion of StackOverflow... [Marking up a search result list with HTML5 semantics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255109/marking-up-a-search-result-list-with-html5-semantics)

Answer (score 2):

If your search results are ranked (probably by relevance), you should use an `ol` element. Each result would be its own `li`. If each result consists of more than a link (e.g. with text snippet, author name, publishing date etc.), use `article` for it, too.

`ol` describes that the results are ranked, `article` describes that each result represents a self-contained entity (that *could* be syndicated in a feed).

I gave a [markup example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11970336/1591669) as answer to another question:

```
<ol start="1">

  <li id="1">
    <article>
     <h1><a href="url-to-the-page.html" rel="external">The Title of the Page</a></h1>
     <p>A short summary of the page</p>
     <footer>
       <dl>
         <dt>Categories</dt>
         <dd><a href="first-category.html">First category</a></dd>
         <dd><a href="second-category.html">Second category</a></dd>
         <dt>File size</dt>
         <dd>2 <abbr title="kilobyte">kB</code></dd>
         <dt>Published</dt>
         <dd><time datetime="2010-07-15T13:15:05-02:00">Today</time></dd>
        </dl>
      </footer>
    </article>
  </li>

  <li id="2">
    <article>
     …
    </article>
  </li>

</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Article and Section weren't introduced in order to further abuse the standard, but to have a clear connection between tags and content. You should use them only when you're indeed describing sections and article instances.

Search results are necessarily a list, and should be used within `<li>` tags. It doesn't really matter, though, whether you use an ordered one or not.