# What is the correct semantic for the members of a search result items?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have the following image representing what i want to do:
[image: semantics of the results members]
The "Search Results" Title is a h2 semantically speaking. The "Search Result Title 2018" would be a h3.

My question is what would "Date & Time", "Fees", "Credit" and "Location" would be?
Some suggestion that were given to me were:
 - titles (h4)
 - strong
 - definition term (dt) and the text next to them the definition description (dd)

It's importat to note that the elements "All", "Events" and "News" are part of a ul list, but i was wondering if they could be also titles h3, and if that's the case then it will make the "Search Result Title 2018" a h4.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Related: [Marking up a search result list with HTML5 semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3255109/1591669)

Answer (score 1):

`<strong>` is not appropriate. `<strong>` is not a replacement for typographic bold, and semantically it doesn't make sense to place "importance" on either the labels or the data using `<strong>`.

A `<dl>` with `<dt>`s for the labels and `<dd>`s for the data is the best fit here. HTML doesn't place very much linguistic meaning in its heading elements, so `<h4>` wouldn't be *wrong* to use, but `<dl>` is made for the kind of content you have here.

Comment: Would `<label>` be completely wrong outside of a form? It seems like these serve the same purpose.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Yes, `<label>`s are intended as form labels only, and have substantial functionality built in to make them work with form controls.